# Where is memcached stored?

Tags: memcached

I understand memcached provides you quicker access to data that is stored in short-term memory, but whose memory is it using. Is it on the server? Is it on another database that is different than regular SQL dbs. Is it on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in **main memory (RAM) of a machine** (typically a separate m/c or a cluster of m/c with more memory - memcache server or cluster).

Memcached (the actual service of memcache) is an in-memory key-value store. The speed come from the fact that all the data is available in RAM, While a typical DB will store data in persistent storage. Also, the key-value ensures O(1) access to every data.

Hope it helps!